# Redux Toolkit API with TypeScript - providesTags/invalidatesTags have unexpected type?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

Trying to implement a Redux Toolkit API with Typescript.  I'm getting errors in the following code for my `invalidateTags` and `providesTags` properties.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'; import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

interface Album { id: number; title: string; userId: number; }

interface User { id: number; }

interface FetchAlbumsResult { albums: Album[]; }

interface AddAlbumMutationResult { album: Album; }

interface RemoveAlbumMutationResult { id: number; }

const albumsApi = createApi({ 
  reducerPath: 'albums', 
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ 
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3005', 
    fetchFn: async (...args) => { 
      return fetch(...args); 
    }, 
  }), 
  endpoints(builder) { 
    return { 
      removeAlbum: builder.mutation<RemoveAlbumMutationResult, Album>({ 
        invalidatesTags: (result, error, album) => { 
          return [{ type: 'Album', id: album.id }]; 
        }, 
        query: (album) => { 
          return { 
            url: /albums/${album.id}, 
            method: 'DELETE', 
          }; 
        }, 
      }), 
      addAlbum: builder.mutation<AddAlbumMutationResult, User>({ 
        invalidatesTags: (result, error, user) => { 
          return [{ type: 'UsersAlbums', id: user.id }]; 
        }, 
        query: (user) => { 
          return { 
            url: '/albums', 
            method: 'POST', 
            body: { 
              userId: user.id, 
              title: faker.commerce.productName(), 
            }, 
          }; 
        }, 
      }), 
      fetchAlbums: builder.query<FetchAlbumsResult, User>({ 
        providesTags: (result, error, user) => { 
          const tags = result!.albums.map((album) => { 
            return { type: 'Album', id: album.id }; 
          }) || []; 
          tags.push({ type: 'UsersAlbums', id: user.id }); 
          return tags; 
        }, 
        query: (user) => { 
          return { 
            url: '/albums', 
            params: { 
              userId: user.id, 
            }, 
            method: 'GET', 
          }; 
        }, 
      }), 
    }; 
  }, 
});

export const { useFetchAlbumsQuery, useAddAlbumMutation, useRemoveAlbumMutation, } = albumsApi; export { albumsApi };
```

Example error:

```
Type '(result: RemoveAlbumMutationResult | undefined, error: 
FetchBaseQueryError | undefined, album: Album) => { type: string; id: 
number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ResultDescription<never, 
RemoveAlbumMutationResult, Album, FetchBaseQueryError, 
FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined> | undefined'.   Type '(result: 
RemoveAlbumMutationResult | undefined, error: FetchBaseQueryError |
 undefined, album: Album) => { type: string; id: number; }[]' is not 
assignable to type 'GetResultDescriptionFn<never, 
RemoveAlbumMutationResult, Album, FetchBaseQueryError, 
FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined>'.     Type '{ type: string; id: 
number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly 
FullTagDescription<never>[]'.       Type '{ type: string; id: number; 
}' is not assignable to type 'FullTagDescription<never>'.         
Types of property 'type' are incompatible.           Type 'string' is 
not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322) endpointDefinitions.d.ts(454, 
5): The expected type comes from property 'invalidatesTags' which is 
declared here on type 'Omit<EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<Album, 
BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, 
FetchBaseQueryMeta>, RemoveAlbumMutationResult> & { ...; } & { ...; } 
& MutationExtraOptions<...>, "type"> | Omit<...>'
```

I've tried looking at the documentation for Redux Toolkit, but not examples using tags have given me any hints so far.  I have lots of Javascript and older Redux experience, but I'm relatively new to TypeScript and Redux Toolkit.

Just trying to get this to compile successfully.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly answered my own question.

You need to add a `tagTypes` property to define the tags you want to provide/invalidate.

The one thing I still don't have an answer for is to how invalidate more than one kind of tag at the same time, mainly cause I'm not sure how to mix types in TypeScript, but that seems like a pretty edgy case anyway.